# $\langle 7, 3 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 7, 4 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$, right?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm not in a math class (haven't been in years) but if this question about $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ appears in some textbook, I wouldn't be surprised.

What I have done: $$1 \times 7 + (3 - \sqrt{-5})(3 + \sqrt{-5}) = 21$$ shows that $\langle 3 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle \subset \langle 7, 4 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ and $$(-1) \times 7 + (4 - \sqrt{-5})(4 + \sqrt{-5}) = 14$$ shows that $\langle 4 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle \subset \langle 7, 3 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$.

But I have this nagging feeling I have ignored some small but important detail.

Comment: Why does the first equation you wrote allow you to conclude that $(3 + \sqrt{-5}) \subset (7, 4 + \sqrt{-5}) = I$, and similarly for the second equation? If that were true, then we'd have $1 = (4 + \sqrt{-5}) - (3 + \sqrt{-5})\in I$, and so $I = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: @anomaly I don't use parentheses to denote ideals. But that doesn't rule out the possibility that I have made one or more mistakes along the way.

Comment: Whether you use parentheses or brackets is irrelevant; the point is that your argument that $3+\sqrt{-5}$ lies in the given ideal is wrong.

Comment: Dave's showing his work; it may be completely wrong but at least it lets us know he isn't just expecting us to do his homework. I have a hunch that his main mistake is one of signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signs, plus or minus. *That* is the small but important detail you have overlooked. Try $$1 \times 7 + (-1)(4 - \sqrt{-5}) = 3 + \sqrt{-5}.$$ Thus $3 + \sqrt{-5} \in \langle 7, 4 - \sqrt{-5} \rangle$; $\langle 7, 3 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 7, 4 - \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ and $\langle 7, 3 - \sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 7, 4 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$.

$7$ the number is irreducible though not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. But $\langle 7 \rangle$ the ideal has unique factorization into prime ideals, though those prime ideals may be represented in infinitely many different ways.

The demon's in the details. Mwahahahahahahahaha!